# How to remove taxes if outside EU

Tags: commerce

I have a custom checkout page. I have already included the Swedish taxes of different amounts in my product price. Now the customer wants me to remove the taxes if the buyer is outside the EU. I tried commerce tax remove but couldn't make it happen. 
I was thinking if I use the base price instead of the commerce_order_total['und'][0]['amount'] for order order total and to use base price for products on line items?

Will this be correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have three options:

1) Apply the patch from https://drupal.org/node/1240216. It will give you a rules action that will remove the tax.

2) Always enter product prices without tax, then the VAT rules can just be made conditional based on the customer address.

3) Use commerce_vat (and commerce_eu_vat).

The first one is probably your easiest way out at this point.

Answer (score 1):

[Commerce remove tax](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_remove_tax) seems to work for me when applied to "Calculating the sell price of a product" event. Im using conditions that order has shipping address and the country is not in one EU countries.

Comment: Nice. But it has one open bug. Wouldn't be so bad, but that bug is **[Does not remove tax](https://www.drupal.org/node/2188719)**.

Comment: Yeah that rings a bell. I seem to have also included the same conditions to prevent them getting readded in "Calculate taxes: VAT".

Comment: Posted to that issue just in case the bug is more of a documentation problem.